# Conntrack Command Not Creating Flow Permanently

Tags: ip-conntrack

For connection tracking, the following command sometimes does not create a flow entry. Do you know why the flow entry creation is intermittent?
conntrack -I -n -p udp -s 10.15.109.12 -d 239.10.200.1 --src-nat 10.15.109.60 --dst-nat 239.10.200.1 --sport 60003 --dport 7000 --reply-dst 10.15.109.60 --reply-port-src 7000 --reply-port-dst 60003

Comment: Whatever you're attempting, conntrack will not properly track multicast traffic. I have a feeling that's because of this being multicast that you won't get the results you expect. Perhaps you should explain the actual ("big picture") goal? This could be an XY problem (https://xyproblem.info/)